# Can jmeter be used to load test native desktop applications?

Tags: jmeter

We have a wintop application written in Java mainly. Can we use Apache jmeter to do load testing of 300 users for desktop application?

Answer (score 0):

If you use command line Parameters, maybe, but it is not made for Testing of GUI Applications. For that, you Need robots like assertj-swing, or what you used for programming.

Comment: Use cases for load testing are - login ,search and few clicks. Can this be achieveable?

Comment: Depending what you used for the GUI there are some Tools out there.  assertj-swing is for Swing applications, it is a fork of FEST. TestFX if you have JavaFX. But for JMeter, there is no way because it cant simulate a mouseclick, or select the Button from a Form and simulate the mouseclick Event etc.

Comment: Just searched for new Tools for GUI Testing, retest.de Looks interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

How do you imagine 300 users of a desktop applications? A desktop application is normally being used by 1 user only therefore you rather need to user [profiling tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) (i.e. [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) or [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/)) in order to detect slowest components and perform all the necessary optimisations.

You can use JMeter only in the case when your desktop application relies on [**backend server(s)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_and_back_ends#Back-end_focused), in this case you might want to check whether the backend is capable of supporting 300 concurrent desktop applications. Also be aware that you need to assess the [network protocol(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols) your application uses - JMeter has to support it in order to be used for testing. If you're lucky enough and your application uses [HTTP (or HTTPS) protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP) - you will even be able to record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), check out [How to Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter) article for more details.